# Ошибка отображения таблицы в DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, datagridview, ado

В предыдущих моих программа этот код прокатывал. Может что не так
сделал в этот раз. В общем я хочу программно отобразить столбцы по
моим размерам. Если я добавляю

```
KassaDGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

отображение по всей ширине, то
возникает ошибка при запуске программы

> System.NullReferenceException
> HResult=0x80004003   Сообщение = Ссылка на объект не указывает на
> экземпляр объекта.   Источник = System.Windows.Forms   Трассировка
> стека:    в System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBand.set_Thickness(Int32
> value)    в System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn.set_Width(Int32
> value)    в ABS58.ABSFORM.tablekassaload() в
> C:\Users\User\source\repos\ABSKassa\ABSKassa\Form1.cs:строка 54

и указывает на строку

```
 KassaDGV.Columns[0].Width = 40;
```

Раньше-то
работал код. Если ту строку убрать. ТО поля делаются по размеру, но
таблица не во весь экран

```
query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Kassa";
dbAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlConn);
SqlCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dbAdp);
dbTable = new DataTable();
dbAdp.Fill(dbTable);
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dbTable;
KassaDGV.DataSource = bs;
KassaDGV.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
KassaDGV.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
KassaDGV.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
KassaDGV.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
KassaDGV.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
KassaDGV.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
KassaDGV.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
KassaDGV.Columns[5].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
KassaDGV.Columns[0].Width = 40;
KassaDGV.Columns[1].Width = 40;
KassaDGV.Columns[2].Width = 150;
KassaDGV.Columns[3].Width = 17;
KassaDGV.Columns[4].Width = 300;
KassaDGV.Columns[5].Width = 50;
KassaDGV.Columns[6].Width = 70;
KassaDGV.Columns[7].Width = 120;
KassaDGV.Columns[8].Width = 70;
KassaDGV.Columns[9].Width = 150;
KassaDGV.Columns[0].HeaderText = "№ п/п";
KassaDGV.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Дата";
KassaDGV.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Клиент";
KassaDGV.Columns[3].HeaderText = "VIN авто";
KassaDGV.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Наличные";
KassaDGV.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Эквайринг";
KassaDGV.Columns[6].HeaderText = "Комментарий";
KassaDGV.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Профит";
```

Comment: Вам надо выбрать, либо вы задаете вручную размеры колонок, либо используете `AutoSize`. Этот параметр кстати [можно задать для каждой колонки в отдельности](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumn_AutoSizeMode). Задайте для части колонок размер в пикселях, а для части, которые должны растягиваться - `AutoSize`.

Comment: @aepot Этот код работал в предыдущих программах и там все колонки с разнйо шириной. Как тогда сделать во весь экран таблицу? Чтобы все колонки были моих размеров но таблица во весь экран была?

Comment: `KassaDGV.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;`